# google cloud disabled publickey?

Tags: linux, debian, cloud

I was sshd_config change disabled publickey then I don't connecting server.

I have a user but user have not privillege.

Google cloud debian 9 server, bitnami wordpress deploy server

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check documentation that describes [how to connect to the instance using ssh](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced).
2. You may also [check troubleshooting SSH documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh).
3. You may also try to use  [`gloucd compoute ssh`.](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh) where you can even [connect as a service account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#sa_ssh_manual)

If above does not work for you. Please update your question with more details like: precise error message that you get, user,